# How to access from parent form to a certain child form generated in ng-repeat without the need to add things like frmChild {{$index}}?

Tags: angularjs

How to access from `frmParent` to a certain `frmChild`?  (without the need to add things like: `frmChild {{$index}}`).

```
<div ng-form="frmParent"> 
How to know frmChild (i.e at index 3) $pristine value from HERE
    <div ng-form="frmChild" ng-repeat="item in mct.listOfElements">
        {{item.Name}}:
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.Value" /> Pristine: {{frmChild.$pristine}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [working example](https://plnkr.co/XE3jjcUeRJ5TfbFVoA5G) to play with what i'm talking about.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Is the goal to have conditional markup/code based on whether all child elements are pristine? Or does it have to be a single child (e.g. "_at index 3_" like you typed...)?

Comment: @AndrewElliott $pristine at index 3 is just an example. The goal is just to know if there is any way to access child forms independently without the need of create independent names foreach child. Cause I guess angularjs create independent child forms automatically watching the way that it works so should be any way to access them indecently outside the ng-repeat. Also naming child’s with just one name make it easier to handle an read on HTML markup.

Comment: but does it work to know if any are not pristine ... e.g. in [this forked example](https://plnkr.co/edit/FWD2fmXdmDO2GRsz3xWt?p=preview)?

Comment: @AndrewElliott it works referencing inside ng-repeat, but if you want to know which form is not $pristine = true outside it, you lost the reference. You know  that any form in ng-repeat is not $pristine= true but you can't access to this unless do something like Alex M proposed.

Comment: What is the end goal? Do you want to apply certain styles to non-pristine child forms, display certain attributes of such child forms in the parent form, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You can use unique names for your child forms, ex. `item.Name` if it's supposed to be unique:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mct.listOfElements" ng-form="{{item.Name}}">
    {{item.Name}}:
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.Value" /> Pristine: {{frmParent[item.Name].$pristine}}
</div>
```

And then refer to any required child form by it's name:

```
D now is pristine: {{frmParent.D.$pristine}}
```

Please see the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/FAZ9R3w871lruvsuoTft?p=preview).

Comment: It's a good way but I was thinking in something without the need to have a dynamic ng-form in the ng-repeat element. Because if I just put ng-form="frmChild" internally Angular need to generarte independent forms or something to make those forms independents. I would like to know how to access to that (array or whatever) and query for an specific form outside the ng-repeat.